# How usual are the comparative sentences like "the number of those under 6 years of age is higher than of those over 70"

Tags: comparatives

I found the following sentences in *Corpus of Contemporary American English*.

> (1)the number of those under 6 years of age is *higher than of those over 70*.
>
> (2)the population density of Nuer areas is consistently *lower than of Dinka areas*.
>
> (3)The life expectancy for the Russian women is somewhat *longer than of males*.

I was taught that in comparative constructions like the sentences above we have to use the pronoun **that** to represent the head of the subject in the subordinate clause as in (1'),(2'), and (3')

> (1')the number of those under 6 years of age is *higher than* **that** *of those over 70*.
>
> (2')the population density of Nuer areas is consistently *lower than* **that** *of Dinka areas*.
>
> (3')The life expectancy for the Russian women is somewhat *longer than* **that** *of males*.

Was my teacher wrong?
How usual are comparative sentences like (1),(2), and (3)?

Comment: Your version is correct, but so is the original. Repetitive words can be omitted when their absence does not change the meaning of the sentence. E.g. "I go to McDonald's more often than [I go to] Burger King".

Comment: I'd say that these are at least bordering on the unidiomatic. Not all deletions are equally acceptable.

Comment: The second "of" in those sounds weird to me. *The number of those under 6 years of age is higher than those over 70*, for instance, is fine.

Comment: That is far more complicated than it seems.

For instance, *the number of those under any age* is not higher; it’s greater . That’s one of the differences between *older* and *taller*.

For instance, *The life expectancy for the Russian women is somewhat longer than of males* should be *Life expectancy for/of Russian women is somewhat greater than that of men*.

The population (density) of Nuer areas is consistently lower than that of Dinka areas.